# getting error in compiling ffmpeg library

Tags: android, windows, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg library in one of my app.While compiling it,i am getting following error:

```
$ ./build_android.sh
./build_android.sh: line 113: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/build_android.sh: line 113: `function build_one
```

This is the script i am using for it:

```
#!/bin/bash
######################################################
# Usage:
# put this script in top of FFmpeg source tree
# ./build_android
# It generates binary for following architectures:
# ARMv6 
# ARMv6+VFP 
# ARMv7+VFPv3-d16 (Tegra2) 
# ARMv7+Neon (Cortex-A8)
# Customizing:
# 1. Feel free to change ./configure parameters for more features
# 2. To adapt other ARM variants
# set $CPU and $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS 
# call build_one
######################################################
NDK=~/C:/android-ndk-r8b
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86
function build_one
{                                                                             
./configure --target-os=linux \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
    --arch=arm \
    --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
    --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
    --disable-everything \
    --enable-demuxer=mov \
    --enable-demuxer=h264 \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --enable-protocol=file \
    --enable-avformat \
    --enable-avcodec \
    --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
    --enable-decoder=mjpeg \
    --enable-decoder=h263 \
    --enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-parser=h264 \
    --disable-network \
    --enable-zlib \
    --disable-avfilter \
    --disable-avdevice \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
}
make clean
make  -j4 install
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a


#arm v6
#CPU=armv6
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-marm -march=$CPU"
#PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one

#arm v7vfpv3
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=$CPU "
PREFIX=./android/$CPU
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
build_one

#arm v7vfp
#CPU=armv7-a
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=$CPU "
#PREFIX=./android/$CPU-vfp
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one

#arm v7n
#CPU=armv7-a
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -marm -march=$CPU -mtune=cortex-a8"
#PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=--enable-neon
#build_one

#arm v6+vfp
#CPU=armv6
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-DCMP_HAVE_VFP -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=$CPU"
#PREFIX=./android/${CPU}_vfp 
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one
```

Please tell me what is the problem with it? I have tried many solutions but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply have a unix / dos file (lr/lf) issue? Maybe a dos2unix on the file will help?